# can we use Indy Socket threads for some heavy executions?

Tags: c++builder

I am using `TIdTCPClient` and `TIdTCPServer` components of Indy Sockets for sending and receiving messages between objects of a class called Agent.Each Agent is responsible for doing a particular task and starts execution after receiving the message. I know that `TIdTCPServer` opens a thread when a message is received and `OnExecute` Event is executed on this additional thread. In fact my final goal is to do a parallel computation, so  I am handling a series of heavy calculations in `OnExecute` Event. Is this approach for multi-thread programming and parallel computation a good one? Can we use the additional thread of Indy Sockets which is opened for receiving messages for a heavy computation? if not, what is the alternative? For example can I use `TThread`objects to handle this parallel computation?

Comment: "*I know that `TIdTCPServer` opens a thread when a message is received*" - no, it creates a new thread when a client connects to the server. The `OnExecute` event is then called in a continuous loop within that thread until the client disconnects. `TIdTCPServer` has no concept of messages, that is the responsibility of your code to handle.

Comment: You are right. `TIdTCPServer` creates a thread. As a bottom line I want to know that, can we do a series of computations in `OnExecute` event to increase speed of computations?

Comment: You can do whatever you want in the `OnExecute` handler, knowing that it is already running in a dedicated thread. The real question is, do you want to block socket I/O for that thread while the calculations are being performed? Or do you want to run multiple calculations in parallel from the same client while the client does other things?  What is your actual goal?  Can you provide an example?

Comment: Suppose that we are going to plus the numbers in a specific range. If this range is pretty wide, for instance [1, 10^20], you will have trouble finding the answer, 1+2+3...+10^20, with just one thread. But if you send a message to 10 different servers and break this heavy operation into 10 separate ones, you can find the answer 10 times faster by means of 10 threads created for `OnExecute`  event handler. Actually I have done it and the speed of calculations has increased dramatically  But I am not sure this is the real purpose of Indy Socket thread.

Comment: why are you using a remote server to do this, instead of just creating threads on the client side? In any case, using socket threads for this is a waste of port resources. The client can create one connection to one server, send the calculation criteria, and then the server can create additional threads (or better, use a thread pool) to perform the calculation and return the result to the client.